# Angular use private library

Tags: angular, npm, shared-libraries

I developed a library that I then published on a repo so that I could use it in other projects via a npm

Except that when I launch my project I have the following error :

```
ERROR in Cannot resolve type entity i3.FontAwesomeModule to symbol
```

My library has the following dependencies:

```
import * as i0 from "@angular/core";
import * as i1 from "./myComponentInLib.component";
import * as i2 from "@angular/common";
import * as i3 from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome";
import * as i4 from "@angular/router";
import * as i5 from "angular-svg-icon";
```

My project in which I install the library contains some dependencies that are in the lib but not all. Do I have to install the other dependencies manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you have to install peer dependencies manually in the project you are utilizing the library component.

It is mentioned in the angular documentation : https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#use-typescript-path-mapping-for-peer-dependencies

> While developing a library, you must install all peer dependencies through devDependencies to ensure that the library compiles properly. A linked library will then have its own set of Angular libraries that it uses for building, located in its node_modules folder. However, this can cause problems while building or running your application.